# How to retrieve href that contain specific text in Beautifulsoup 4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://example.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

property_list = soup.find(class_='listing-list ListingsListstyle__ListingsListContainer-cNRhPr hqtMPr')
property_link_list = property_list.find_all('a',{ "class" : "depth-listing-card-link" },string="View details")
print(property_link_list)
```

I just got an empty array. What I need is to retrieve all the hrefs that contain `View details` text.

This is an example of the input

```
<a class="depth-listing-card-link" href="https://example.com">View details<i class="rui-icon rui-icon-arrow-right-small  Icon-cFRQJw cqwgEb"></i></a>
```

I am using Python 3.7.

Comment: Can you post the url? If not, check if that page is loaded using jscript; in that case, requests can't handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the last 2 lines of your code to:

```
property_link_list = property_list.find_all('a',{ "class" : "depth-listing-card-link" })
for pty in property_link_list:
    if pty.text=="View details":
        print(pty['href'])
```

My output is:

```
/property/bandar-sungai-long/sale-7700845/
/property/bandar-sungai-long/sale-7700845/
/property/bandar-sungai-long/sale-4577620/
/property/bandar-sungai-long/sale-4577620/
/property/port-dickson/sale-8387235/
/property/port-dickson/sale-8387235/
```

etc.